# Mongoose saving empty array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a array and i trying to insert it with mongoose but in return i got a empty array what i'm doing wrong,

my schema:

```
let postSchema = mongoose.Schema({


    date            : { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    name            : String,
    desc            : String,
    type            : []


},{collection: 'Post'});
```

my insert:

```
console.log(req.body.type); //here i have something like ["Teste1","Teste2"]
let post = new Post({ 
                       name: req.body.descricao, 
                       desc: req.body.desc
                       type: req.body.type
                    });

post.save((err, model) => {

    if (err) console.log(err);

    if (model) console.log(model); //ALL INSERTED but array is just type:[]

})
```

Comment: there's no model argument while saving the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is to specify the type of the array elements.
For example,

```
type: [String]
```

Specifying an empty array is equivalent to Mixed type.
Also check the type of req.body.type

```
console.log(typeof req.body.type)
```